# How to exclude one particular attribute of column from a case statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

Assume that there is a column which has 2 attribute a and b. I only want it to consider only a to the overall case condition. How do I apply that in case statement?

Something like:

```
Case when student> 100 then 'big class'
else ''
End [big class ]
*exclude class 10th.*
```

Comment: I really don't understand the question.  Can you show a table with sample data, and a sample output you want, that demonstrates the problem you're having?

Comment: In SQL and Relational Algebra the terms "column" and "attribute" are largely synonymous. So please be more specific.

Comment: group no no of student  divison 
 grp 1 105                    a
 grp 2 107                    a
 grp 3 108                    b
 grp 4 110                    b
 grp 5 85                    b
 grp 6 84                   a
 grp 7 83                   a
 grp 8 110                   b
 grp 9 105                   a
 grp 10 140                   b
   
 I want that number of students be above 100 and only from divsion A  
 group no no of student  divison 
 group 1 105                  a
 group 2 107                  a
 group 9 105                  a

Answer (score 0):

I don't get your question, If you want to get the "big class" of Divison A ,It is not necessary for using case. or you have additional requirement.

```
;WITH SampleTable(GroupNo,NoOfStudent,Division)AS(
    SELECT 'grp 1',105,'a' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'grp 2',107,'a' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'grp 3',108,'b' UNION ALL 
    SELECT 'grp 4',110,'b' UNION ALL 
    SELECT 'grp 5',85,'b' UNION ALL 
    SELECT 'grp 6',84,'a' UNION ALL 
    SELECT 'grp 7',83,'a' UNION ALL 
    SELECT 'grp 8',110,'b' UNION ALL 
    SELECT 'grp 9',105,'a' UNION ALL 
    SELECT 'grp 10',140,'b'
  )
  --1
  SELECT * FROM SampleTable WHERE Division='A'  AND NoOfStudent>100
```

```
GroupNo NoOfStudent Division
------- ----------- --------
grp 1   105         a
grp 2   107         a
grp 9   105         a
```

```
--2
SELECT * ,CASE WHEN Division='A' AND NoOfStudent>100 THEN 'big class' ELSE '' END AS [BigClass]
FROM SampleTable
```

```
GroupNo NoOfStudent Division BigClass
------- ----------- -------- ---------
grp 1   105         a        big class
grp 2   107         a        big class
grp 3   108         b        
grp 4   110         b        
grp 5   85          b        
grp 6   84          a        
grp 7   83          a        
grp 8   110         b        
grp 9   105         a        big class
grp 10  140         b
```